How do C++ 20 modules resolve same function name problems in different modules?
I'm trying to apply C++ 20 modules to my new project, but currently met with a big problem.
Say I have 3 modules,

mod1.ixx with mod1.cpp
mod2.ixx with mod2.cpp
mod3.ixx with mod3.cpp

and here's their contents
// mod1.ixx
export module mod1;
export int func();

// mod1.cpp
module mod1;
int func() {
  return 1;
} 

// mod2.ixx
export module mod2;
export int func();
export int goo();

// mod2.cpp
module mod2;
int func() {
  return 2;
} 

// mod3.ixx
export module mod3;
export int func3();

// mod3.cpp
module mod3;

import mod1;
import mod2;

int func3() {
  func();
} 

int goo() {
  return 4;
}

Since mod1 and mod2 both export func(), which does func3() exactly call? Does goo in mod3.cpp implement goo 'declared' in mod2.ixx?
I think having & exporting functions of the same name is quite often in real project, how is this handled in C++ 20 modules?
I tried VS2022+msvc, and func3() calls func() in mod1, but I'm not sure if this is the standard.

I would've expected this to have caused a linker error...

I would say ODR violation -> IFNDR.

Using namesapce avoids name collision.

This doesn't work on GCC or Clang: https://godbolt.org/z/76ex3oMK6

@LHLaurini Is there any compile option to turn this into a linker error in msvc?

@Jarod42 I think I can accept this as an ODR violation, now I'm getting annoyed that msvc doesn'give me any error message, do you know any compiler options to treat it as an error?

Modules and namespacing are orthogonal. A module doesn't have its own namespace. Nothing changed about naming conflicts with modules: Use namespaces to resolve them as always in C++.

@NekomiyaKasane Identifying ODR violations is hard, because in the normal compilation mode only the linker sees the multiple definitions from different translation units. The linker does not actually understand C++ and it also only sees the compiled code. It can't generally detect ODR violations due to mismatch of definitions and even in the cases where it could, I am not aware of any linker actually performing that analysis. If you compile and link in the LTO compilation mode instead, then compilers will probably tell you about these kinds of ODR violations.

@NekomiyaKasane Although, in your specific case the compiler/linker could set it up so that the linker will complain about multiple definitions (because they are not inline that is always an ODR violation). It depends on your linker and compiler whether it will diagnose this.


I think having & exporting functions of the same module is quite often in real project, how is this handled in C++ 20 modules?

Real projects scope their names in namespaces; that's what the namespace feature is for after all. Modules and namespaces are orthogonal features; neither interferes with the other, but neither requires the other either. Good module practice would be to put all of the stuff in a namespace to avoid this sort of thing.
As for this case, the standard is pretty clear:

If multiple declarations of the same name with external linkage would declare the same entity except that they are attached to different modules, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required

So it is not allowed, but compilers/linkers don't have to look for it.
